# Очереди(Queues) в пайтоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, очередь

Есть код, который скачивает файлы из сайта по протоколу ftp, всё это делается в потоках и я создаю очередь, для того что бы потоки выполнялись постепенно:

```
import time
import os
import ftplib
from ftplib import FTP
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue


class Downloader(Thread):
    """
    A threading example
    """

    def __init__(self, queue):
        """Инициализация потока"""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        """Запуск потока"""
        while True:
            list = self.queue.get()
            name = self.queue.get()
            msg = "%s is running" % name
            print(msg)
            # Скачиваем файл
            self.downloading(list, name)
            # Отправляем сигнал о том, что задача завершена

    def downloading(self, list, thread_name):
        ftp = FTP("ftp.cse.buffalo.edu")
        ftp.login()
        ftp.cwd("mirror/X11/Gnome/")
        file_ns = ftp.nlst()
        list_need = list

        print(
            f"[{thread_name}]------DOWNLOADING {len(list_need)} files in {len(file_ns)} directory file range------")
        count = 0

        for file_n in file_ns:
            out_path = os.path.join("C:\\Python_server", file_n)
            if(file_n in list_need):
                try:
                    with open(out_path, 'wb') as f:
                        ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + file_n, f.write)
                    count += 1
                except ftplib.error_perm:
                    print(f"[{thread_name}][!]No permission to " + file_n)
                finally:
                    print(f"[{thread_name}][*]Succefull downloaded {count} files of {len(list_need)}!")

        ftp.quit()
        self.queue.task_done()
        self.queue.task_done()


def create_threads():
    """
    Создаем группу потоков
    """
    queue = Queue(maxsize=2)
    t = Downloader(queue)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
    t = Downloader(queue)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
    list = ["FGO-FOOTER.html", "FGO-HEADER.html"]
    name = "Thread #1"
    list2 = ["README"]
    name2 = "Thread #2"
    queue.put(list)
    queue.put(name)
    queue.put(list2)
    queue.put(name2)

    queue.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_threads()
```

Пример вывода:

```
Thread #1 is running
Thread #2 is running
[Thread #1]------DOWNLOADING 2 files in 19 directory file range------
[Thread #2]------DOWNLOADING 1 files in 19 directory file range------
[Thread #1][*]Succefull downloaded 1 files of 2!
[Thread #2][*]Succefull downloaded 1 files of 1!
[Thread #1][*]Succefull downloaded 2 files of 2!
```

Почему запустился 2 поток, но при этом 1 ещё не завершился?

Разве потоки не должны выполняться по очереди, ведь ещё `self.queue.task_done()` не сработал, но поток запустился.

Comment: Возможно, я не совсем верно понимаю как работают очереди или они не подразумивают выполнение потоков по очереди?Но где же тогда безопасность при изменение глобальных переменных...

Comment: Эта очередь работает по принципу FIFO - first-in, first-out, но при этом 1 поток закончился позже 2.Если два потока поставить в равные условия, и они будут скачивать каждый по 2 файла, то очередь не "багуется" и потоки прекращают свою работу в верном порядке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы создаете очередь

```
queue = Queue(maxsize=2)
```

Затем создаете поток для запуска downloading в очереди

```
t = Downloader(queue)
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()
```

Python создает объект и запускает первую в очереди "загрузку". После этого у вас идут строки

```
t = Downloader(queue)
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()
```

Python опять создает объект и выбирает из очереди следующую "загрузку". Поэтому в консоли видны строки:

```
Thread #1 is running
Thread #2 is running
```

Вот пример лога для очереди из трех элементов:

```
Thread #1 is running
Thread #2 is running
[Thread #2]------DOWNLOADING 1 files in 19 directory file range------
[Thread #1]------DOWNLOADING 2 files in 19 directory file range------
[Thread #2][*]Succefull downloaded 1 files of 1!
[Thread #1][*]Succefull downloaded 1 files of 2!
Thread #3 is running
[Thread #1][*]Succefull downloaded 2 files of 2!
[Thread #3]------DOWNLOADING 2 files in 19 directory file range------
[Thread #3][*]Succefull downloaded 1 files of 2!
[Thread #3][*]Succefull downloaded 2 files of 2!
```

Видно что как только завершился поток Thread #2 из очереди выбран была выбрана следующая задача и запущена во втором потоке - Thread #3.
То есть 2 потока по очереди выбирают из очереди задачи.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста рассказать, как мог начаться поток 2, если первый ещё не закончился(тоесть self.queue.task_done() ещё не выполнился, а поток новый запустился)

Comment: Попробую, но я плохой учитель) первый t.start() создал первый поток, второй вызов t.start() создал второй поток. Второй поток не имеет никаких причин для ожидания завершения заданий первого потока. и первый и второй поток выполняются "while true:" это единственное условие.Они по мере завершения задания будут выбирать из очереди следующее задание. Если бы поток был один, то задания выполнялись бы последовательно.

Comment: А если например мы будем использовать глобальную переменную(ту переменную, которая используется в двух потоках) и будем её изменять, то потоки буду синхронизировано работать, тоесть переменная будет изменятся во втором потоке если изменилась в первом?Или очереди не решают проблемы синхронизации потоков?

Comment: Можете сделать через переменную (думаю это в принципе возможно), можете посмотреть например такой вариант блокировок - http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-threads-synchronization-locks-rlocks-semaphores-conditions-events-and-queues/ (там Lock заголовок и вставки кода подходящие). Но в похожем на ваш вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688550/how-do-i-queue-my-python-locks пишут что эти механизмы лишают код кроссплатформенности незнаю насколько это для вас критично. вот на русском описание самих механизмов синхронизации https://python-scripts.com/synchronization-between-threads